# Is `$(document).on("method1",function(event,param)` thesame as usual function method1(){}?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, eventtrigger

On file1.js, I have this code :

```
$(document).trigger("method1",param);
```

And on file2.js, I have this code :

**code block 1 :**

```
 $(document).on("method1",function(event,param){
    //do something here
    });
```

**code block 2 :**

```
  function method1(){
    // do something here also
    }
```

These are my queries :

1)Can you explain what the difference of those block of codes?

2)What block of codes will be triggered from file1.js?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question

Comment: code block 2 looks unrelated (even if the function has the same name as your custom event).

Comment: @Thilo, so on code block 1, method1 serves as a name of events and not another function ?

Comment: that's right. The function being bound to the event is anonymous in block 1.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you explain what the difference of those block of codes?

The first one binds an event handler to the custom event `method1`. I.e. the handler will be executed in response to the occurrence of event `method1`.

The second one creates a function with name `method1`. That function can explicitly be called via `method1()`.

> What block of codes will be triggered from file1.js?

The first one. The function in code block 2 has nothing to do with the event.

Comment: Thanks sir @Felix Kling for your concise explanation

Answer (score 1):

`$obj.trigger(eventName)` launches *jQuery events*. `obj.method()` launches *methods*. `func()` launches *functions*. You can't invoke a method using `trigger`. So these are the three define-invoke pairs:

```
function func() {
  console.log("function");
}
func();


a = {
  method: function() {
    console.log("method");
  }
};
a.method();


$(document).on('customEvent', function(evt) {
  console.log("event");
});
$(document).trigger('customEvent');
```